# Modifying Levenshtein distance to consider positions, while being symmetric

Tags: algorithm, statistics, string-matching, levenshtein-distance

The Levenshtein distance to convert *SATURDAY* to *SUNDAY* is 3. One way is, delete A at pos 2, delete T at pos 3, substitute R at pos 5 by N.

If I take position number as the weight for positions, the cost will be:

`2 + 3 + 5 = 10`

Similarly, if I convert *SUNDAY* to *SATURDAY*, it requires 2 insertions at pos  2 and 1 substitution at 3, the cost will be:

`2 + 2 + 3 = 7`

As you can see, this modified Levenshtein is not symmetric.

Note that the positions are relative to the original string, even after insertions.

Is there any way to take the positions of letters into consideration, and keeping Levenshtein symmetric, so that `lev(x,y) = lev(y,x)`?

I saw some questions already posted, but they weren't really helpful:
[Modifying Levenshtein Distance for positional Bias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425238/modifying-levenshtein-distance-for-positional-bias)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to take an asymmetrical property and make it symmetrical is to use the average (or other measure) of them: `d'(x,y) = d'(y,x) = (d(x,y) + d(y,x))/2`

One familiar usage of such technique is making the [KL-Divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) symmetrical by applying the same technique. This is known as the [Jensen-Shannon Diversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence)

Comment: I did think about using the average, but wasn't able to come up with a way to avoid/reduce the extra computation. Any ideas?