# Levenshtein divides in too many substrings

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, levenshtein-distance, longest-substring

I've implemented the Levenshtein distance to do signal alignment.
There are cases where Levenshtein doesn't find the solution I want, although it's optimal. For example, I have the strings:

```
  aaabaa
abaaabaaa
```

The algorithm should recognize that it needs to delete the first two and the last character to match the strings:

```
abaaabaaa
x      xx
```

Instead it finds:

```
abaaabaaa
 x  x   x
```

Thus it divides the string in more substring than it needs to.
Is there an extension to the Levenshtein distance, which divides the string in fewest substrings?

Comment: have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425238/modifying-levenshtein-distance-for-positional-bias?rq=1 Two alternative algorithms get mentioned, that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a more complicated edit cost function than the the one the Levenshtein distance uses. You could make n consecutive deletions (or n consecutive inserts) cheaper than n separated delets (or inserts).

This would make the solution you want cheaper than the one the Levenshtein distance found.

Example of a edit cost function which should meet your needs:

```
cost of replace: 2
cost of fist insert: 2
cost of consecutive insert: 1
cost of fist delete: 2
cost of consecutive delete: 1
```

than

```
abaaabaaa
x      xx
```

would have the edit costs: 5

and

```
abaaabaaa
 x  x   x
```

would have the edit costs: 6

So the found solution would be the one you desire with edit distance: 5